# Cisco ASA 5520 AnyConnect Essentials License and IPSec Connections

Tags: cisco, licensing, cisco-vpn, cisco-asa

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you help me with my software licensing question?](https://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-question)

I'm trying to find the answer to this question, but not really getting anywhere. I'm hoping a ServerFault Cisco Licensing expert may be able to help.

We have a new Cisco ASA 5520 that we're using at the moment for an IPSec site-site VPN connection. We're looking at adding the AnyConnect Essentials license to the box, which will enable 750 SSL VPN connections for client machines with the AnyConnect client installed. What I can't quite get an answer to is - will this license affect the box's IPSec capabilities in any way (the [AnyConnect FAQ](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/products/ps8411/products_qanda_item09186a00809aec31.shtml) is a bit vague to me)

I realise that the essentials license won't enable us to use Secure Desktop or clientless SSL connections - neither of which we need. We need IPSec site-site connections, and SSL VPN for client machines with the AnyConnect client installed - is the Essentials license good enough for this, or will we have to shell out for the "premium" licenses?

Edit: In case it's relevant, the box at the moment has a "VPN Plus" license.

Thanks ...

David

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You're IPSec connections will be fine, Adding the SSL VPN license does not magically disable the IPSec connections - which are actually licensed to a ridiculous or unlimited quantity (can't remember off the top of my head.)

You can run them side by side just fine. or even IPSec Client Access VPN/SSL Client Access VPN/P2P IPSec VPN all at the same time.